# clicked.connect не работает

Tags: python, pyqt5

Приложение запускается без ошибок, но после нажатия на кнопку "clear_btn" поля не очищаются.

main.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from untitled import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parant = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.clear_btn.clicked.connect(self.chisti)
        self.ui.quit_btn.clicked.connect(self.vihodi)
        self.ui.rascet_btn.clicked.connect(self.reshai)



    def chisti(self):
        self.ui.text_a.setText(" ")
        self.ui.text_b.setText(" ")
        self.ui.text_c.setText(" ")
        self.ui.text_output.setText(" ")

    def vihodi(self):
        pass

    def reshai(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

untitled.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(457, 257)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.rascet_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.rascet_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 30, 75, 23))
    self.rascet_btn.setObjectName("rascet_btn")
    self.clear_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.clear_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 100, 75, 23))
    self.clear_btn.setObjectName("clear_btn")
    self.quit_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.quit_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 170, 75, 23))
    self.quit_btn.setObjectName("quit_btn")
    self.text_a = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.text_a.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 241, 41))
    self.text_a.setObjectName("text_a")
    self.text_b = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.text_b.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 241, 41))
    self.text_b.setObjectName("text_b")
    self.text_output = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.text_output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 200, 241, 41))
    self.text_output.setObjectName("text_output")
    self.text_c = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.text_c.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 120, 241, 41))
    self.text_c.setObjectName("text_c")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 47, 13))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 47, 13))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 47, 13))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 210, 47, 13))
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.rascet_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output"))
    self.clear_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "clear"))
    self.quit_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "quit"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a = "))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "b = "))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "c = "))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OUTPUT"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль `untitled.py`

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не вызываете переопределенный класс `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):`. Попробуйте так:

```
# . . .

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

    MainWindow = MainWindow()

    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```